# jquery mobile return to index

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, mobile

I have an application with phonegap + jQuery Mobile.
When the app starts, it launches the index.html, and it shows a list (with ajax). When I push on an element of the list or in a header bottom, it changes to other html, and it works fine.
But when I return to index with this:

```
<a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-left" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide"></a>
```

It returns to index.html but no list. It makes the ajax call, because if I put the response in an alert or console.log it shows it, but do not write it in the content div.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show some source code? It's hard to give feedback without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: It is not rare code.
It is only the index with all the code and other html with only the body and the javascript that it needs.

Comment: Without seeing what you're doing it's impossible to know what you're doing wrong.